# after i redirect the right scroll bar appears only if the bottom one appears

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am a newbie in programming, but I encountered a problem I never saw till now.
I got the index page and a login button. After login I redirect to the profile page (using javascript).
Index and Profile got the same css, but when I resize the browser, the Profile page won't show the scroll bar on the right unless the bottom one appears. If I logout and go to the Index page, the problem disappears.

the javasciprt for redirect:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php_scripts/login_check.php' + '?user=' + user + '&psw=' + psw,
            success: function(data) {
                switch(data) {
                    case '0':
                        window.location.replace('admin.php');
                        break;
                    default:
                        $("#mesaj_psw").html('');
                        $("#mesaj_psw").hide();
                        $("#mesaj_psw").html(data);
                        $("#mesaj_psw").addClass('vizibil nok');
                        $("#mesaj_psw").removeClass('invizibil ok');
                        $("#mesaj_psw").toggle(500);
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

the css:

```
body, html {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin: 0;
    font: 1em "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    cursor: default;
    min-width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.text-no-select{
    /*Dezactivwaza selectare textului*/
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                          supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.text-select{
    /*Dezactiveaza selectare textului*/
    -webkit-touch-callout: text; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: text; /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: text; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                          supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
/*
=====================
HEADER
=====================
*/
/*zona header*/
.nav {
    background-color: #222;
    height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*zona meniului care are o latime maxima data*/
.nav-main {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*overflow: visible;*/
}
/*zona logo-ului din meniu*/
.nav-main .logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    height: 64px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #096;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: auto;
    font-family: "Edwardian Script ITC", "Cooper Black", Georgia, Verdana, sans-serif, serif;
}
/*zona meniurilor*/
.nav-main > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*lista meniurilor din meniu*/
.nav-main > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
/*meniul propriu-zis din fiecare lista (link-urile aferente fiecarui meniu)*/
.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
/*schimbarea la mouse peste meniu*/
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*zona din nav, partea dreapta care contine butonul de Log IN*/
/*zona care contine butonul de "Log IN" in nav*/
.user-login {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
/*butonul de "Sign IN"*/
.btn-sign-up {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #09F;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
/*cand se face hover la butonul de sign in*/
.btn-sign-up:hover {
    background-color: #0CF;
    color: #000;
}
/*butonul de "Log IN"*/
.btn-log-in {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #090;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
/*cand se face hover la butonul de log in*/
.btn-log-in:hover {
    background-color: #0F0;
    color: #000;
}
/*zona care contine contul logat in nav*/
.user-logat {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
/*zona in care e afisat numele utilizatorului*/
.utilizator {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    color: #CCC;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    /*font-style: oblique;*/
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
}
/*zona cu setarile utilizatorului logat*/
.setari {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
/*butonul setari al utilizatorului logat*/
.btn-setari {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.btn-setari:hover {
    background-color: #9494b8;
}
/*butonul logout al utilizatorului logat*/
.btn-logout {
    float: right;
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.btn-logout:hover {
    background-color: #F90;
}
/*
=====================
CONTENT
=====================
*/
/*zona de continut*/
.content-area {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.continut {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 850px;
    float: left;
    color: #282828;
}
.reclame {
    border-left: #CCC 5px double;
    width: 175px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    /*border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-left: inset 2px #FFF;
    border-right: inset 2px #FFF;*/
}
.reclame-1, .reclame-2, .reclame-3, .reclame-4, .reclame-5 {
    height: 145px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/*
=====================
FOOTER
=====================
*/
/*zona de footer*/
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
/*zona meniului care are o latime maxima data*/
.footer-meniu {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer-meniu > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-meniu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 30px;
}
.footer-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
/*schimbarea la mouse peste meniu*/
.footer-item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    /*background-color: #666;*/
}
.afis_utilizatori {
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
}

/*
=====================
APLICABILE
=====================
*/
.space-content-footer {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.opacity-085 {
    opacity: 0.85;
}
.opacity-080 {
    opacity: 0.80;
}
.opacity-075 {
    opacity: 0.75;
}
/*clasa active pentru butoane*/
.active {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #CF9;
}

/*
=====================
FORMURI
=====================
*/
.fereastra {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: $f2f2f2;
}
form {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=number], input[type=email], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin: 5px 0px 15px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=radio] {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px 15px 5px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.verde {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.verde:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
.rosu {
    background-color: #ff704d;
    color: white;
}
.rosu:hover {
    background-color: #ff3300;
}
.galben {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #45a049;
}.galben:hover {
    background-color: #cccc00;
}
.mesaj {
    width: auto;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.ok {
    color: #090;
    border: 2px solid #090;
}
.nok {
    color: #F00;
    border: 2px solid #F00;
}
.vizibil {
    display: block;
}
.invizibil {
    display: none;
}
.link_buton {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    /* ...and now for the proper property */
    transition:.5s;
}
.link_buton:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #90F;
}
/*
=====================
CAND ECRANUL SE MICSOREAZA SUB 1060px pe latime
=====================
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    .nav {
        width: 1060px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .content-area {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
    }
    .footer {
        width: 1060px;
        position: relative
    }
}
```

profile page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/template_pacient.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title></title>
</head>
<body class="text-no-select">
<div class="nav" id="header">
  <div class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="user-logat">
      <div class="utilizator"></div>
      <div class="setari"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-area" id="content"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="container" -->
  <div class="continut" id="continut"> CONTINUT </div>
  <?php require_once("php_scripts/afisare_reclame.php"); ?>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
  <div class="space-content-footer" id="space-content-footer"> </div>
</div>
<div class="footer" id="footer">
  <div class="footer-meniu">
    <?php require_once("php_scripts/afisare_utilizatori.php"); ?>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_scripts/index_pacient.js"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript" src="java_scripts/auto_roll_reclame.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_scripts/logout.js"></script>
</body>
```

Could you pls try to help me?
P.S: sorry if it is a simple problem I do not see...

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: @vel Just did :) forgot about it, sorry :)

Comment: can you update with your issue in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/ku6f2oas/

Comment: @vel I did it. Try it now pls. https://jsfiddle.net/ku6f2oas/1/

Comment: share me the updated fiddle url.

Comment: @vel Done. Ty for taking your time to help me. https://jsfiddle.net/ku6f2oas/1/

Comment: jsfiddle doent support php code. can update jsfiddle with your issue? can you create some data with static value?

Comment: @vel I never used this one...so I am sorry if I can't do more. https://jsfiddle.net/ku6f2oas/4/ I made some changes...don't know if it is ok.

Comment: your issue in this fiddle?

Comment: @vel I am really sorry mate, I found my problem: had a non closed <div> and for that the page didn't put the right scroll bar...I am really sorry if I made you waste your time.

Comment: its ok. No problem.

Comment: @vel can I do something for your time? is a way to give you a badge or something that reflects your good intentions?

Comment: I didn't get you clearly.

Comment: @vel is there a way on stackoverflow to give you reputation or something for tacking time to help me? I mean you tried to help me and I'd like to reward you somehow (don't know how stackoverflow works from this point of view)...

Comment: it wont give any reputation. No issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a div closing tag.
I am really sorry for making you waste your time...

```
<div class="nav" id="header">
  <div class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="fisa" class="nav-item">Fisa</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="cauta" class="nav-item">Cauta</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="discutii" class="nav-item">Discutii</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="noutati" class="nav-item">Noutati</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="user-logat">
      <div class="utilizator"> Logat: </div>
      <div class="setari">
        <div><a href="setari" class="btn-setari" id="btn_setari">Setari</a></div>
        <div><a href="logout" class="btn-logout" id="btn_logout">Iesire</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you again and lots of apologies.